# Excel : Next Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I have a Sheet

[image: Material - Rates-MRP]

I Found Lowest Rate for ABC with = MIN(B4,D4,F4) i.e. D4 = 6.9
I want to have corresponding value of MRP in Adjacent CELL i.e. E4

I tried INDEX, MATCH, OFFSET, CELL...but couldnt get it.
When I researched, all have given solution column wise minimum value with Adjacent CELL.

I want Row wise minimum value with Adjacent CELL.

One More help Please, 
in Column J, 
I want to have a Company name(in the header) of Minimum Rate.....
like if D4 is Minumum then I want "SunPharma" in J4....
Could you? Please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=index(c4:g4, match(MIN(B4,D4,F4), b4:f4, 0))
'alternate
=index(c4:g4, match(h4, b4:f4, 0))
```

Comment: How could you be so genius ? which drink should I get you at weekend ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: One More help Please, in Column J, I want to have a Company name of Minimum Rate.....like if D4 is Minumum then I want "SunPharma" in J4....Could you? Please ?

Comment: If those are merged cells then `=index(b$2:f$2, match(h4, b4:f4, 0))`